# Dated help section

Tags: feature-request

Whilst reading [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I wondered when it was published.

Could we get an added date & last edit date on articles in the help section?

Comment: It was last edited May 2014; only moderators can see the revision history though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You may not know why, but I'm still asking : why only mods? Is there really some risk at letting the end user know the last revision date? Might help settle some meta discussions actually :)

Comment: Is there something in particular on that page that you think needs updating? Other than idle curiosity, what purpose does the display of when it was last edited serve?

Comment: Why did you date a help section?

Comment: @TZHX someone might say "hey, I haven't read this in a year, and it was updated last month, maybe I'm due for a refresher"?

Comment: Or: "Jeez, it's already a month old.  Better ask if it is still relevant instead of reading it".

Comment: This isn't really relevant information. The information in the help center is the be all and end all for the ever changing "right now". If it changes in the future, then it changes, what is the point in knowing when it was changed? The only thing that you need to know is what the current guidance is.

Comment: @TinyGiant Patrice's comment sums up the "why" perfectly. Forums from the 90s have time-stamped rule & help threads. Seems strange that SO does not.

Answer (score 2):

This was going to be a comment in response to [your comment above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303331/dated-help-section?noredirect=1#comment237866_303331), but it spanned four comments so I'm just going to post it as an answer.

Stack Exchange is really good at showing you only relevant information. In all honesty, I find having a site that gives you too much irrelevant information actually makes it harder to find relevant information. I don't see any actual benefit from having this information available. If I say ["hey, I haven't read this in a year"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303331/dated-help-section?noredirect=1#comment237806_303331), I'm going to stop right there and go read it again to make sure that the information I'm telling people to find there is still there.

It isn't like everyone on the site is going to be notified when it does get updated, so the only people who see the date will be those who are reading it for the first time, or those who are going back to read it again anyways. So, those who are reading it for the first time are going to read it whether there is an edited date or not, and those who are going back to read it again are going to read it again whether there is an edited date or not.

How will this affect anything other than showing you "Hey this hasn't been edited in a year, maybe I should post a question on meta about how outdated it is". If you have a suggestion for improving the information contained within the help center, you will have that suggestion whether there is an edited date or not. In that case, you should bring your specific suggestion to meta as a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) so that we can vote on that specific change.

I fail to see what advantage you would gain from being able to see when the content was edited without being able to view the revision history. The fact is that the help center is the way it is and will stay that way until it is changed. If / when it is changed, the previous revision will have no meaning anymore so the fact that there even was a previous revision is completely irrelevant because the only relevant information would be the information contained within the newest revision.

Comment: I still think the date **is** relevant. What about users who say they didn't realise about a particular article? "Well, you've been here 3 years and it's a 5 year old article."

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you don't know about something in the help center, and you show signs of that, other users will kindly direct you to the relevant information. That's the great thing about a community moderated site, those who have the information share the relevant information with those who don't. I repeat information from the help center to users on a regular basis, then those users propagate that information and onwards and so forth.